# How do I color the same line chart with 2 different colors with a certain condition?

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I actually work on power BI with some simple date(just integer). And I try to make a line chart in blue. But when the values go to 0 I want the grey line chart... I try to make 2 dinstinct line chart but it doesn't work and I try to change my x-axis from continuous to categorical but it show me something weird...

here's an quicklook on my date and chart:
[image]

Comment: I've had a quick look, the conditional color formatting (based on values) is not available in the line chart, It is available in the bar chart though.

Comment: It was available but with the newest version they delete the feature... But it tried to put into bar chart and then  convert it into line chart but it doesn't work ! :/